# Rounding to 2 decimal places but keeping 4 decimal places in C#

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding

I would like to round a number to 2 decimal places but also keep the trailing 2 zeros so for example 425.1382 to 425.1400
I've tried below examples but it doesn't seem to work

```
var amount = Math.Round((value * rate), 4);
profit = Decimal.Parse(amount.ToString("0.####"));
```

or

```
var amount = Math.Round((value * rate), 4);
profit = Decimal.Parse(amount.ToString("0.##00"));
```

Comment: You're parsing it into a decimal.  Those zeroes will disappear when you parse it into a numeric structure.  I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen.  4.00 and 4 are the same value.  Round your number to two decimal places.  If you need the extra zeroes later, format it as a string.

Comment: Why? The trailing zeros have no effect on calculations. It's only when you format the number to a string that the number of decimals has any meaning and even then, it's governed by the formatting function, not the number

Comment: Define "it doesn't seem to work", what doesn't work?

Comment: Hi Amy, I'm doing it this way as I'm verifying the value (which is calculated - my expected) with the actual database value which is in this format. The numeric scale is set to 4 on the database so when I retrieve it from the database for verification it has the 2 trailing zeros added

Comment: It really shouldn't matter. How are you comparing?  Because this is true: `decimal.Parse("1.0000") == decimal.Parse("1")`

Comment: @EBrown this won't work as you expect it. At least in SQL Server, decimals or numeric types *preserve* the number of digits, even trailing zeroes. A text comparison will fail but loading the data to a *decimal* should return the same amount

Comment: @Antirip which database? How are you comparing values? Even if the database stores numeric values with 4 or 6 decimals, loading the value to a `decimal` variable will return an equal number to the one you are calculating

Comment: @EBrown numeric database types *are* decimals - in fact in Oracle even int  is an alias for decimal. There's no need to convert if the table actually contains decimals instead of eg strings

Comment: @EBrown the OP wrote `The numeric scale is set to 4 on the database`. This would suggest that the database does use a numeric type with a scale of 4

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos Yes I think I need to 'chop off' the trailing zeros from my actual results from the database

Comment: @Antirip  why? How are you testing? Equality is *not* affected by the trailing zeroes. `123.47m == 123.4700m` returns true even if the second value is loaded from the database. Please post the code that fails so we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

When you convert to a numeric type you give up all unnecessary digits. You need to convert the Decimal to a String before displaying.

Answer (score 0):

The `_invoicingCurrencyProfitAmount = Decimal.Parse(profitAmount.ToString("0.####"))` line is returning a decimal. Decimal does keep all zeroes, the problem is 100% in where are you printing the value. 
If you are trying to write this in `Console`

```
 Console.Writeline("{0:F4}", _invoicingCurrencyProfitAmount);
```

where `{0:F4}` means "Format as fixed-point", with four numbers after point. Of course, you can use this anywhere by using `string.Format`.

Answer (score -1):

var _profitAmount = Math.Round((saleMarginValue * exchangeRate), 4);
_invoicingCurrencyProfitAmount = Decimal.Parse(profitAmount.ToString().PadRight(2,'0'));

Answer (score -2):

```
var d = 425.1382.ToString("0.##") + "00"; // "425.1400"
```